# Should the same element be selected using jQuery everytime a Backbone View is rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is it necessary to select the same DOM element and do something to it for every Backbone View that is rendered? Only one of this View exists at any one time.

For example, say Bootstrap's Tabs (tabbable plugin) have to be used on a particular backbone View `Product`. Is it correct to include the tabbable plugin's initilization code in the `render` function?

```
render: function() {

    this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );

    // Activate Twitter Bootstrap Tabs
    $('.tab-bar').tab();
    $('.tab-bar .tab:first').tab('show');
    $('.tab-bar .tab').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');    });

    return this;
}
```

Or is there a way to just call this selector once, and it will fire for all elements with class `.tab-bar` including those that have yet to exist.

Similarly, if I want a click handler on the first tab

```
$('.tab:first').click(function(){
    console.log('hey!')'
}
```

do I place it in that view's `render` function? If I do, wont it create many `click` event listeners if  the view is rendered multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind event listeners in the initialize method, not in the render. Unless you're going to re-render the DOM element more than once.

EDIT

```
window.myView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        'click #someElementID': 'do_something',
    },

    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'do_something');
    },

    .....

    do_something: function(e){
        console.log("A click was made!", e.currentTarget);
    }

});
```

Comment: Is it alright to bind to a DOM element before it exists? Like binding to `$('.tab:first')` then rendering it later with `render`. I will be re-rendering the same View but with different model attributes/data. So like the DOM element will be rendered, then closed, then rendered again (most likely with different model data). Its kindof like View for a popup box

Comment: You can't bind an event listener to a DOM element that doesn't exist. The best you can do is set some events handlers in the events object in your view. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I cant seem to use Twitter Bootstrap's `.tab()` within the `events` object I think...

Comment: The ```do_something``` method will receive and argument called ```event```. You can use it to access the DOM element that created the click event. Then you can use ```$(event.currentTarget)``` to convert that to a jQuery object, and then you can use the .tabs() method.